# projections and index on 2D nested arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-indexes

```
> db.foo.save({'foo': [{f0: 'a', f1: 'b'}, {f0: 'c', f1: 'd'}]})
> db.foo.save({'foo': [{f0: 'a', f1: 'e'}, {f0: 'f', f1: 'g'}]})
> db.foo.save({'foo': [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]})
> db.foo.save({'foo': [['a', 'e'], ['f', 'g']]})
> db.foo.find({}, {'foo.f1': 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf7cbeb971f4081ea48a"), "foo" : [ { "f1" : "b" }, { "f1" : "d" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf83beb971f4081ea48b"), "foo" : [ { "f1" : "e" }, { "f1" : "g" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf88beb971f4081ea48c"), "foo" : [ [ ], [ ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf8dbeb971f4081ea48d"), "foo" : [ [ ], [ ] ] }
> db.foo.find({}, {'foo.1': 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf7cbeb971f4081ea48a"), "foo" : [ { }, { } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf83beb971f4081ea48b"), "foo" : [ { }, { } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf88beb971f4081ea48c"), "foo" : [ [ ], [ ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf8dbeb971f4081ea48d"), "foo" : [ [ ], [ ] ] }
```

I have a couple of questions related to nested arrays like this (note that virtually all the SO questions with nested array in the title actually refer to single arrays nested in the root document, not 2D nested arrays. To the best of my ability to tell, this isn't a duplicate).

- Is there any way to perform a projection, as above, on 2D nested arrays?
- How would I create an index on the 2nd element of the arrays in the foo array? Again, presumably foo.1 wouldn't work.

I know the Right Answer (TM) is to Not Do That And Use An Array Of Subdocuments, Dummy (NDTAUAAOSD) but a) curiosity - I can't seem to find an answer and b) unfortunately, circumstances beyond my control dictate the document structure.

**UPDATE:** Clarification of what I'd want to see from the projections:

```
db.foo.find({}, {'foo.1': 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf88beb971f4081ea48c"), "foo" : [ ['b'], ['d'] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dddf8dbeb971f4081ea48d"), "foo" : [ ['e'], ['g'] ] }
```

Basically slicing across the inner arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the positional `$` operator for projections:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

While i'm not entirely sure what your query is trying to project on, here's an example:

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb90"), "foo" : [  {  "f0" : "a",  "f1" : "b" },  {  "f0" : "c",  "f1" : "d" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb91"), "foo" : [  {  "f0" : "a",  "f1" : "e" },  {  "f0" : "f",  "f1" : "g" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb92"), "foo" : [  {  "f0" : "a",  "f1" : "b" },  {  "f0" : "c",  "f1" : "d" },  { "f0" : "a", "f1" : "z" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb93"), "foo" : [  [  "a",  "b" ],  [  "c",  "d" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb94"), "foo" : [  [  "a",  "e" ],  [  "f",  "g" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb95"), "foo" : [  [  "a",  "e" ],  [  "f",  "g" ],  [  "a",  "z" ] ] }

// get the array document which has a field "f0" which matches "a"
b.foo.find({ "foo.f0" : "a" }, { "foo.$" : 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb90"), "foo" : [  {  "f0" : "a",  "f1" : "b" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb91"), "foo" : [  {  "f0" : "a",  "f1" : "e" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb92"), "foo" : [  {  "f0" : "a",  "f1" : "b" } ] }
// ^ see that the last return document only returns the first array element match

// get the array element of the foo array
> db.foo.find({ "foo" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$in" : [ "a" ] } } }, { "foo.$" : 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb93"), "foo" : [  [  "a",  "b" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb94"), "foo" : [  [  "a",  "e" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5321ac073ac852396029fb95"), "foo" : [  [  "a",  "e" ] ] }
// ^ see that the last return document only returns the first array element match
```

Comment: Clarified the OQ to specify what I'm hoping for re projecting 2D arrays.